# xpath based on multiple rules

Tags: xpath

I have the below rule to match an image which works fine

```
//div[@class="wp-caption alignright" or @class="area"]//img
```

The problem is that the page is created dynamically and it now contains another image before the one I need to match, so I have a new xpath rule to accommodate for this

```
(//div[@class="body"]//img)[2]
```

Is there a way to combine these 2 rules into one as I actually need both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine then with union operator:

```
//div[@class="wp-caption alignright" or @class="area"]//img | (//div[@class="body"]//img)[2]
```

You can test it here: http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/cf36d1bd-01c6-41ea-8e9b-2099cc75cf80